# How to find abbreviations as words in a C# regular expression

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have been given a list of strings to find as whole "words" in my string.  Generally, using the `\b` anchor works for most things except when I'm trying to find the & character as a word or if the abbreviation has a dot after it since the `\b` doesn't match between the space and the & character, or after a period and space.

For instance to find these strings:

```
&
b&w
bpi
p.
```

I'm trying to write something like:

```
\b((&)|(b&w)|(bpi)|(p\.))\b
```

In a test string:

```
my b&w and & and p. test.
```

I've also tried using `\s` to check for whitespace but I don't want to capture the whitespace and I haven't been able to figure out how not to.  It would also then need to check for beginning and ending of the string as well I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using word boundaries (\b)  you could use look around assertions for (space) OR ^beginning or $end of line..  like so:

```
(?<=^|\s)([^\s]*)(?=\s|$)
```

Working regex example:

http://regex101.com/r/rJ0wU4

Test string:

```
my b&w and & and p. test.
```

Matches:

```
"my", "b&w", "and", "&", "and", "p.", "test."
```

Comment: This is very close and got me where I needed.  The front and back sections are what I needed.  The middle part should be changed to what I had originally so we are only capturing the specific strings I need.   `(?<=^|\s)((&)|(b&w)|(bpi)|(p\.))(?=\s|$)`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use all abbrs in one group like:

```
(^|\s+)(&|b&w|bpi|p\.)(\s+|$)
```

Comment: It looks like that only matches `b&w` and doesn't match `&` or `p.`.  Presumably because `&` and `.` are considered non-whitespace characters themselves.

Comment: That wouldn't work out either because I'm looking for "whole words".  If I were making the spaces optional, I might as well just not include the `\s`.  For instance, this would match the word `Philip.` and not just `p.`.

Comment: I understand, check again, please